# My family tree on Ancestry..I cannot find this feature any more "Find a person in this tree"

Tags: ancestry.com

If I want to find a particular person in my family tree on Ancestry, I use the field in the top right-hand corner of the screen that says "Find a person in this tree". However, I cannot find the feature any more. How can I find a particular person in my tree?

Comment: For some reason neither ways are available. There is no 'Find Person' button and there is no icon to the right of my tree name near the top left of the profile page.

Answer (score 5):

The two ways that I use to do this in Ancestry.com now are both one click away from the front page.

The first method is to:

1. click the GO TO TREE button in the middle of the front page
2. click the FIND PERSON button near the top right of the tree page

[image: ![enter image description here]

3. type in the person's name

The second method is to:

1. click the Last viewed person in the middle of the front page
2. click the icon to the right of your tree name near the top left of the profile page

[image]

3. type in the person's name